# How do I add an image to a LinkedIn Signature?

Tags: linkedin

I would like to know how to add an image to a LinkedIn signature much in the same way that you are able to in ones [Gmail Signature](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=8395).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LinkedIn Email Signature - No Longer Supported**

Customized email signatures can no longer be created on the LinkedIn site. However, you can create an auto-signature from within your email client, and then direct your contacts to your customized public profile URL. [Learn how to customize your profile URL](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/global/id/87/ft/eng).

You can customize your public profile URL *when you edit your public profile*. Custom public profile URLs are available on a first come, first served basis.

1. Move your cursor over **Profile** at the top of your homepage and select
   **Edit Profile**.
2. You'll see a URL link under your profile photo like
   **www.linkedin.com/in/yourname**. Move your cursor over the link and
   click the **Settings** icon next to it.
3. **Note:** "Update your public profile settings" will show up if you
   don’t have a public profile.
4. Under the **Your public profile URL** section on the right, click the
   Edit icon next to your URL.
5. Type the last part of your new custom URL in the text box.
6. Click **Save**.

**Notes:**

- Your custom URL can have 5-30 letters or numbers. Don't use spaces,
  symbols, or special characters.
- We recommend using a variation of your name and/or your professional
  brand since you’ll share this URL with people so they can find your
  LinkedIn profile. Some job applications may also ask you for your
  LinkedIn profile URL.
- The customizable part of the URL is case insensitive. This means
  using JohnSmith, johnsmith or johnSmith will all point to the same
  profile.
- If the URL you want isn't available, please select a different one.
  We can't make custom URLs available to members upon request.
- You can change your URL up to 5 times within 180 days. Once you have
  changed your URL for the 5th time, you won’t be able to change it for
  another 180 days. Changing your URL several times may make it hard
  for people to find you.
- If a member uses a URL and then changes it, that URL will be
  unavailable for use by other members for 180 days.
- If you navigate to a previously claimed URL, you may see a page that
  reads **Profile Not Found**.